# Number of flips required to detect a biased coin using Chebyshev's Inequality

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm trying to solve the following question:

"Given 2 coins where one is fair but the other comes up heads 3/4 of the time.  One coin is picked and tossed n times.  Use Chebyshev's Inequality to determine the smallest n which allows us to determine which coin is picked with 95% confidence."

I already previously calculated that the probability of having picked the unfair coin given that you flipped n heads in a row is $3^n / (2^n + 3^n)$ but I'm not sure if that is relevant at all here.

I know Chebyshev's inequality is $P(|X - E[X]| \ge a) \le Var[X]/a^2$, but I have no idea what $a$ would be in this problem.  Or perhaps this is not the correct way to be thinking about this at all...

Comment: The question is phrased wrong since to determine the smallest $n$, you need to explicitly compute the probabilities. Moreover, Chebyshev is far from tight … but alas

Comment: In any case, set the right hand side to $.05$ and solve for $a$

Comment: Sorry could you clarify a little further on what you mean by "set the right hand side and solve for a"?  Also what would X and E[X] be in this case?

Answer (score 1):

It is not totally clear to me what the question is asking for.

Let's suppose the question did not mention Chebyshev's inequality, and that

- you use $n=42$ tosses
- you choose the fair coin if you see $26$ or fewer heads (the binomial probability of this with a fair coin is $0.9558$)
- you choose the $\frac34$-heads coin if you see $27$ or more heads (the binomial probability of this with a $\frac34$-heads coin is $0.9584$).

*For those interested, these numbers come from the R code*

```
n <- min(which(qbinom(0.05, 1:1000, 3/4) > qbinom(0.95, 1:1000, 1/2)))
c(n, qbinom(0.95, n, 1/2), qbinom(0.05, n, 3/4))
# 42 26 27
pbinom(26, n, 1/2)
# 0.9557852
1 - pbinom(27-1, n, 3/4)
# 0.9583713
```

If that was a satisfactory approach, then perhaps a similar approach using Chebyshev's inequality might be to say:

- With a fair coin, the expected number of heads is $\frac12n$ and the variance is $\frac14n$
- With a $\frac34$-heads coin, the expected number of heads is $\frac34n$ and the variance is $\frac3{16}n$
- You want each probability from your statement of Chebyshev's inequality to be no more than $0.05$ and for the two intervals not to overlap

  - $0.05 = Var(X)/a^2$ gives $a=\sqrt{5n}$ for the fair coin
  - $0.05 = Var(X)/a^2$ gives $a=\sqrt{\frac{15}4n}$ for the $\frac34$-heads coin
  - You then want $\frac12n+\sqrt{5n} \le \frac34n-\sqrt{\frac{15}4n}$
  - which gives $n \ge 140+80\sqrt{3} \approx 278.6$.
- With $n=279$ tosses, as it has to be an integer, you get

  - $\frac12n+\sqrt{5n}\approx 176.85$ as the top of the fair coin interval, and
  - $\frac34n-\sqrt{\frac{15}4n} \approx 176.90$ as the bottom of the $\frac34$-heads coin interval,
- so you choose the fair coin if you see $176$ or fewer heads and choose the $\frac34$-heads coin if you see $177$ or more heads

*This demonstrates @Andrew's comment that the Chebyshev inequality is far from tight. In fact the (binomial) probabilities far exceed $95\%$, as can be seen with*

```
pbinom(176, 279, 1/2)
# 0.9999958
1 - pbinom(177-1, 279, 3/4)
# 0.9999932
```

Answer (score -1):

For a fair coin, the probability of *n* heads (not necessarily in a sequence) *m* throws = $\frac{^mC_n}{2^m}$. So the probability of getting 2 heads in a row with 3 coin tosses = $\frac{^3C_2}{2^3} = \frac{3}{8}$. A *simple rule* (cf. Chebyshev) could be that if a coin toss yields $> 3$ heads in $8$ throws, the coin's *loaded*.

For a sequence of *n* heads in *m* tosses, the probability = $\frac{1}{2^m}$ (observe *n* is *not* part of the equation, perhaps it's $^nC_n$). In other words in $m$ tosses, *n* heads in a row should be $\approx 1\%$ of $m$.

A good sample of simulations/actual experiments should give us a rough idea of how *n* heads in *m* throws *vary*. Then a *mean*, then a *variance*, then a *standard deviation*. After that we use the *actual number of heads* in *m* throws, calculate its $z$ score and it's $\geq 2$, we clinch the diagnosis with $95\%$ confidence: unfair/loaded coin.

How does Chebyshev's formula compare with this *modus* I just outlined?